# php image manipulation corrupting text inside image

Tags: php, html, image, php-gd

I have a html form which submits base64 string of an image to php. The php script base64 decodes the string, gets the image resource using `imagecreatefromstring()` and then saves the resource to a `png` file. When I open the saved file, I see that the file is not the same as the image I uploaded. Wherever there is text in the image, that part is appearing as a color filled rectangle. Attaching the version of image uploaded and image saved. I have the latest version of php installed (v7), and latest version of php-gd library, running on ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I am unable to figure out the issue. Please help.

**image i am trying to upload**

[image: image i am trying to upload]

**image which was saved by php**

[image: image which was saved by php]

Comment: Looks like transparency (alpha channel) gets misinterpretated...

Comment: If you're not manipulating the image in any way why create a GD resource?  Simply use `base64_decode()` and then `file_put_contents()`. That way the data is not modified at all.

Comment: I am converting the image from any image type to .png

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution. Before calling `imagepng()` to save the image resource to a file, I had to call 2 functions: `imageAlphaBlending()` and `imageSaveAlpha()` to preserve the transparency of the image. My earlier code used to work with php 5.5 but may be this is changed in php 7.